# How to set 100% scale in MS Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I can't set 100% scale in Visio, it always rounds to 106%.

[image]

Visio version is 2010.

Comment: I had the same problem with Visio 2002. It probably is not version specific.

Comment: Does clicking where it says 106% and specifying 100% in the Zoom dialog help?

Comment: No. It changes back to 106%. Simultaneously it shows 100% in dialog.

Comment: In Visio 2013 you can click on the percentage and write 100%, but then you get 101%